# add network to hyper-v machine

Tags: networking, hyper-v

I am having a problem building a 32-bit virtual Windows 8 machine on my 64-bit Windows 8.1 laptop with a wireless network adapter. I opened the Virtual Switch Manager window in the Hyper-V Manager app and added a new external network. The dropdown box recognized my wireless adapter, which I selected. In the settings for my VM, I selected this adapter for my network device.

When I boot the VM, it appears that the network is constantly trying and failing to connect. Later, I found that my wireless device was no longer working from the host OS. I had to remove the device I created with the Virtual Switch Manager to get my real machine back on the internet.

Will this configuration work?

Comment: Not a programming question - ask on [su]

Answer (score 0):

In "Virtual Switch Manager" when you right click the host on the left panel, on the vSwitch in question make sure "Allow management operating system to share this connection" is checked.

(If it's unchecked that means the host can't use that physical wireless adapter.)

Answer (score -1):

dacDave, if you're using the VM for internal purposes only (testing, dev environment, etc.) or don't need a physical connection to the network adapter, create a internal one for the VM, share the host adapter and connect the internal to the shared adapter. I found this is the simplest & error-prone way in this excellent article from Ben Armstrong:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/virtual_pc_guy/archive/2008/01/09/using-hyper-v-with-a-wireless-network-adapter.aspx